Is there a better and more efficient way to identify clusters from an image?
So I have a video of moving bacterias which I have converted to images. Now I have to find the clusters of bacterias in each image. We define two neighboring bacteria as members of the
same cluster if their centers of mass are separated by less than a distance R and if their motion directions differ by less than an angle alpha. A dynamic cluster is defined to include all bacteria that are connected to at least one other bacterium that satisfies the local distance and motion direction criteria.
This is a sample image:

I first stored the coordinates of the COM and angle of each contour in a dictionary. I identify the  first contour and make it a standard. Then I check for another contour which is closest to the first contour and its angle differs by the least value. If this is within the given criteria then they both are in group 1. Then the second contour becomes the new standard and this process is repeated till there are no other contours which satisfy the criteria. All of these contours are then said to belong in group 1. This process is again repeated to form other groups. But my question is, is there easier way to do this? My method takes a lot of time and is not accurate. Is there a better algorithm or function to do the same?
